# Community ♦ has gained sentience and is posting bad comments, what should I do?

Tags: bug, review, stackexchange

On Thursday [the review queues changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013). Whilst the change is hopefully for the better in the long term. In, hopefully, the short term, <sup>[[5]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272)</sup> the release has a number of issues. <sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369148)</sup>

There are a few I'd like to highlight:

1. Community ♦ is posting comments which are good for Stack Overflow, but are bad on Code Review and other sites. <sup>[[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369052) [[3]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369158#369158)</sup>
2. Users cannot flag Community's ♦ comments. <sup>[[4]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067)</sup> As such you can't use the normal means to make moderators aware of the problematic comments Community ♦ is now posting.

If you notice any problematic comments please notify a moderator. As moderators can edit the comment's text.
If you are unable to flag the comment please feel free to post a link to comments under this question (as comments not answers) or as a message in [the 2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: We need to give Community a suspension for this... ;-)

Comment: Most of issues will be solved by [Resolving Community user and “share feedback” issues in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369272/916629).

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I have included a link to that - [5]. It should be noted that the first issue will only be half fixed, by allowing users to post comments under either the user's account or Community. And doesn't aim to fix the issue around the contents of Community comments due to resource constraints.