# Do the default first questions Share feedback canned comments make sense for Code Review?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queue

Most sites have 2 default *Share feedback* comments in the First questions queue:

**Question is unclear**

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

**Question is too broad**

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

However Code Review is more open-ended than other Stack Exchange sites so questions are not really 'unclear' more so than their code is unclear or the context of their code is unclear.

And questions cannot really be unfocused as we are asking for a review of our code which is inherently open-ended and general most of the time.

I know that these can be at least somewhat customized per-site because Stack Overflow has a couple extra feedback reasons about too little or too much code.

But when would the default *Share feedback* comments be used on Code Review? Can they be customized to better fit the needs of this particular site?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Community ♦ has gained sentience and is posting bad comments, what should I do?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10712)